# Rails 3 - Atom Feed Help Needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Am having trouble getting the Atom feed function to work on my blog. I am using the Kaminari plug-in to paginate my articles - 6 per page. With the code below, when a user clicks on the RSS Feed image they are asked to log-in instead of subscribing to the feed! Any help would be appreciated with this issue...

[image: screenshot]

**application.html.erb**

*page head* <%= auto_discovery_link_tag(:atom, feed_path, { :title => "My ATOM Feed" }) %>

*page body* <%= image_tag("feed.png", {:alt => 'Atom feed', :class=>"feed"}) %>Subscribe

**routes.rb**

```
match '/feed' => 'articles#feed', :as => :feed, :defaults => { :format => 'atom' }
```

**articles_controller**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]

# GET /articles
# GET /articles.xml
# display articles on the home page

def index
@articles = Article.published.page(params[:page]).per(6).ordered

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @articles }
  format.atom { render :atom => @articles }
end
end


# GET /articles/1
# GET /articles/1.xml
def show
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@comment = Comment.new(:article=>@article)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @article }
end
end



# GET /articles/new
# GET /articles/new.xml
def new
@article = Article.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @article }
end
end


# GET /articles/1/edit
def edit
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
authorize! :edit, @article
end

# POST /articles
# POST /articles.xml
def create
  #authorize! :create, @article
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])
  @article.user_id = current_user.id

respond_to do |format|
  if @article.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Worry was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @article, :status => :created, :location => @article }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @article.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PUT /articles/1
# PUT /articles/1.xml
def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
authorize! :update, @article
respond_to do |format|
  if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
    format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Worry was successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @article.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end


# DELETE /articles/1
# DELETE /articles/1.xml
def destroy
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
authorize! :destroy, @article
@article.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(articles_url) }
  format.xml  { head :ok }
end
end

end
```

**views/articles/feed.atom.builder**

```
atom_feed :language => 'en-US' do |feed|
feed.title "mysite.com"
feed.updated(@articles.blank? ? Time.now : @articles.first.created_at)

@articles.each do |article|
feed.entry article, :published => article.accepted do |entry|
  entry.title article.title

  entry.author do |author|
    author.name article.user.fullname
  end
end
end
end
```

Comment: Sooo...what is the issue?  What is happening?

Comment: @Gazler - nothing is happening so can't pin it down exactly

Comment: Can you provide your whole `articles_controller` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update this line in your `articles_controller`:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
```

... with:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show, :feed]
```

This will prevent the request for authentication.

Comment: That has stopped the auth. request alright, its still not picking the articles tho?

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1) Add `:url` and `:root_url` to the `atom_feed` call.

2) Change:

```
feed.updated @articles.first.created_at
```

to:

```
feed.updated(@articles.blank? ? Time.now : @articles.first.created_at)
```